# Como usar HasMorePages nesta ocasião?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Bom, tenho um sistema de impressão aqui que está funcionando perfeitamente. O problema que estou enfrentando é em relação ao uso da bool `HasMorePages`. Não estou sabendo como implementá-la para imprimir múltiplas páginas caso o conteúdo não caiba em uma. Deem uma olhada no código:

```
    string[] legenda = { "Produto", "Preço", "Data da compra" };
    float[] retLarguras = { 400.0F, 100.0F, 400.0F };
    float retEspacamento = 15.0F;
    float distancia = 25.0F;

    float espacamentoVertical = 250F;
    float espacamentoHorizontal = 20.0F;

    bool imprimiuLogo = true;

    private void printDocumento_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
            var Fonte = new Font("Arial", 9);
            var FonteB = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);

            if (imprimiuLogo)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.logoI, 20, 20);
                imprimiuLogo = false;
            }

            StringFormat alinhar = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);

            alinhar.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

            Cliente cliente = Clientes[listaClientes.SelectedIndex];

            RectangleF retInicial = new RectangleF(espacamentoHorizontal, espacamentoVertical, retLarguras[0], distancia);
            RectangleF retAtual = retInicial;

            int coluna = -1;

            RectangleF retORC = new RectangleF(20F, 210F, 0, 0);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("Orçamentos do(a) cliente {0} listados abaixo.", cliente.Nome), Fonte, Brushes.Black, retORC, alinhar);

            for (int col = 0; col < legenda.Length; col++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(legenda[col], FonteB, Brushes.Black, retAtual, alinhar);
                retAtual.Offset(retEspacamento + retLarguras[col], 0F);
            }

            foreach (var cli in cliente.Produtos)
            {
                coluna++;

                retAtual = retInicial;
                retAtual.Offset(0F, (float)(coluna + 1) * distancia * 1.5F);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(cli.NomeProduto, Fonte, Brushes.Black, retAtual, alinhar);

                retAtual.Offset(retEspacamento + retLarguras[0], 0F);
                retAtual.Width = retLarguras[1];
                e.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("R${0}", cli.ValorProduto), Fonte, Brushes.Black, retAtual, alinhar);
                retAtual.Offset(retEspacamento + retLarguras[1], 0F);
                retAtual.Width = retLarguras[2];
                e.Graphics.DrawString(cli.DataCompra, Fonte, Brushes.Black, retAtual, alinhar);
            }

            RectangleF retVAL = new RectangleF(20F, 50F, 500F, 0);
            retVAL = retInicial;
            retVAL.Height = 0;
            retVAL.Width = 780F;
            retVAL.Offset(0F, (float)(coluna + 1) * distancia * 1.5F + 35F);
            string stringF = "\n\nAgradecemos a preferência.";
            double total = cliente.Produtos.Sum(x => x.ValorProduto);
            double porcentagem = total * 5 / 100;
            double totalD = total - porcentagem;
            if (cliente.Observacoes != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("Valor total: R${0}\nValor com desconto para pagamento à vista (-5%): R${1}\n\n''{2}''", total, totalD, cliente.Observacoes) + stringF, Fonte, Brushes.Black, retVAL, alinhar);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("Valor total: R${0}\nValor com desconto para pagamento à vista (-5%): R${1}", total, totalD) + stringF, Fonte, Brushes.Black, retVAL, alinhar);
            }
    }
```

Para chamar o evento, eu tenho:

```
internal void Imprimir()
    {
            Margins margem = new Margins(20, 20, 20, 20);
            printDocumento.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = margem;
            printPrevisao.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Sei que para fazer isso tenho que usar `e.Graphics.MeasureString` e checar se o número de caracteres das strings que são escritas não ultrapassou o limite da página, mas com este meu sistema não estou sabendo como fazer isso. No caso, as colunas desenhadas que não couberem na página devem ser passadas para a outra página junto com a string que é escrita abaixo delas.

Comment: quando achar uma resposta que lhe agrade no período da recompensa, marque ela e comente nela com o meu nome. Irei dar a recompensa :D

Comment: HasMorePages é usado para indicar que o evento será invocado de novo, no seu caso não tem como usar, o código todo está embutido dentro do delegate, refatorar é necessário. O MeasureString também não vai ajudar, porque o seu código usa retângulos para formatar espaçamento, os cálculos não irão bater, mas é possível calcular quanto ficou fora da página matematicamente (tamPag - TamRetSomados). Será bem difícil ajudar sem um exemplo funcional que possa ser reproduzido.